# Invalid indirect reference in decodeIndirectRef

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am trying to return an android devices ID number from Java to C++:

Currently I have the following:

in C++:

```
jstring Java_com_incket_OnePlayRL_OnePlayRL_uniqueCode (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring passCode)
{
    const char *ucstr;
    ucstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(passCode, 0);
    CCLog("String id is %s", ucstr);        
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(passCode, ucstr);
}
```

on Java side:

```
public native String uniqueCode (String passCode);

static Context mContext;
private static Activity me = null;

String identifier = null;
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (tm != null)
          identifier = tm.getDeviceId();
    if (identifier == null || identifier .length() == 0)
          identifier = Secure.getString(me.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    uniqueCode (identifier);
```

Currently the java part gets called at start up within another method. This is what gets return in the log:

```
String id is e384d223aab74897
Invalid indirect reference 0xfffffe5c in decodeIndirectRef
VM aborting
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 25515
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your function should return some `jstring` value:

```
jstring Java_com_incket_OnePlayRL_OnePlayRL_uniqueCode(...)
```